# Mock objects returns null

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-test

I have below Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringTestConfig.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void testProcessInvoice() throws SQLException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("abc");
        when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);
        Assert.assertNotNull(userService);
        User savedUser = userService.save(user);
        Assert.assertEquals("abc", savedUser.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

I have below `SpringTestConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
public class SpringTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserService userService() {
        return Mockito.mock(UserService.class);
    }
    @Bean
    public UserRepository userRepository() {
        return Mockito.mock(UserRepository.class);
    }
}
```

call to `User savedUser = userService.save(user);` returns `null` user object. I am not able to figure it out why it is returning null.

**EDIT:**
`UserRepository` is `JpaRepository`, if this is a problem

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration needs to return a real UserService:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserService userService() {
        return new UserServiceImpl(); // or whatever your implementation is 
    }
    @Bean
    public UserRepository userRepository() {
        return Mockito.mock(UserRepository.class);
    }
}
```

Mocks are for collaborators, not for the thing you're testing.

Comment: I have followed what you said, like `return new UserServiceImpl(userRepository());` now `userService.save(user)` calls actual implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your `UserService` is a mock object, and has no defined behavior for dealing with the `#save(User)` method.

Mocking the object under test is probably not what you are after here.  I would recommend your objects under test are instantiated in the test, and injected with the mocks or stubs of the objects that they utilize.

Comment: yes, correct so I had run again with `when(userService.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);` and it returns the object. how does it test the functionality of `userService.save` since I have defined mocking behavior on that?

Comment: You aren't if you are mocking your object under test!